# Difficulties changing text color of two component UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I want to be able to change the text color for both rows, I'm using this code:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{

    NSString *rowItem = [weight objectAtIndex: row];


    UILabel *lblRow = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView bounds].size.width, 44.0f)];

    [lblRow setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

    [lblRow setTextColor: [UIColor redColor]];

    [lblRow setText:rowItem];

    [lblRow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return lblRow;
}
```

It makes the two components in the UIPickerView the same data but it changes the color. How do I make it two change the color for both components without changing the data?

Comment: Instead of "I want to be able to change the text color for both rows", you mean "...both components", right? Why not use the `component` parameter to decide how `rowItem` is set?

Comment: @Anna Correct I just want to change the color of the text for both components without screwing up the data I already am using as sources.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have two params `row` and `component`

you will have to if condition the component and get the data you want

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    if (component == 0)
        NSString *rowItem = [weight objectAtIndex: row];
        UILabel *lblRow = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView bounds].size.width, 44.0f)];
        [lblRow setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [lblRow setTextColor: [UIColor redColor]];
        [lblRow setText:rowItem];
        [lblRow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        return lblRow;
    } else {
        // Adjust the second component 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView attributedTitleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component ==0)
    {
        NSString *title = @"maulik";
        NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
        return attString;
    }
    if(component ==1)
    {
        NSString *title = @"fenil";
        NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];

        return attString;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to what this is doing.  Code dumping is usually discouraged.  It'd be nice for the OP to know what you're doing in case they're not an expert.